# Regular expression for matching strings without both bba and abb

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

> What is a regular expression that will match all words without *both* `bba` and `abb`? (If a word has only one of them, it's fine.)

I tried `(a+ba)*(bb+b+^) + b*`. I'd like to know if this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct - for example, you do not allow any strings starting with bba, while there are many valid ones (eg bba itself).

One possible way of achieving this is to construct a DFA, then convert that to a regular expression, but that is quite a complicated process. In this case, there is a simpler method just by considering the options.

If the word doesn't have two consecutive bs, then it is obviously valid. This means all bs, except possibly the first, are preceded by an a. There are a few ways to write this, eg:

```
b(a+ab)* + (a+ab)*
```

If the word does have consecutive bs, then it cannot have an a both before and after. In other words, there can only be one 'long' string of bs, and it must come at the very start or the very end. So it is either:

- all bs:

```
b*
```

- a string of bs, followed by a, followed by anything with no consecutive bs

```
b*a(b(a+ab)* + (a+ab)*)
```

- the reverse of the above

```
(b(a+ab)* + (a+ab)*)ab*
```

So one complete answer is:

```
b(a+ab)* + (a+ab)* + b* + b*a(b(a+ab)* + (a+ab)*) + (b(a+ab)* + (a+ab)*)ab*
```

There of course may be nicer and shorter answers!

Comment: of course I do :)...please

Comment: You distinguish more cases than you really need here: one simpler version would be just $b^*(a+ab)^* + (a+ba)^*b^*$

Comment: This is a wrong expression, because it can produce $abb$ as a substring (from $ab^*$ in the end of the expression). @KlausDraeger's expression is also wrong for the same reason.

Comment: But $abb$ or $bba$ occurring as substrings is fine! They just should not occur both in the same word.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that...